# why GTK compilation didn't work?

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I am trying to compile my GTK program which is written in C language under Linux but the terminal still 
showing me this character ">" and the pointer still blinking ,I am successfully compiled before with this command

```
gcc -o bt  transfer_file_program_GUI.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

and also i removed the libgtk-3-dev and installed again and still same problem

Comment: no just this character and blinking pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably  an unmatched quote in your input. I suspect that one of your back quotes is a single quote.

Instead of back quotes you can use the `$()` syntax (which is easier to type correctly):

```
gcc -o bt  transfer_file_program_GUI.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

If that doesn't help you should check for unmatched quotes in the output of

```
echo $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)
```